# Split dataframe into 20 groups based on column values

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I am fairly new to R and can't find a concise way to a problem.

I have a dataframe in R called `df` that looks as such. It contain a column called `values` that contains values from 0 to 1 ordered numerically and a binary column called `flag` that contains either 0 or 1.

```
df
value     flag
0.033     0
0.139     0
0.452     1
0.532     0
0.687     1
0.993     1
```

I wish to split this dataframe into X amount of groups from 0 to 1. For example if I wished a 4 split grouping, the data would be split from 0-0.25, 0.25-0.5, 0.5-0.75, 0.75-1. This data would also contain the corresponding flag to that point.

I want to solution to be scalable so if I wished to split it into more group then I can. I am also limited to the tidyverse packages.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you limited to the tidyverse packages? Sounds like an odd constraint to me.

Comment: My work only allows that.

Comment: Sounds like you better look for another job then. Limiting your employees to only tidyverse-packages is (imho) one of the most stupid contraints you can impose (not blaming you though). You will miss a lot from the rich ecosystem R has.

Answer (score 1):

if `n` is the number of partitions:

```
L = seq(1,n)/n

GroupedList = lapply(L,function(x){
                 df[(df$value < x) & (df$value > (x-(1/n))),]
               })
```

I think this should produce a list of dataframes where each dataframe contains what you asked.

Comment: This is not scalable. If I wanted 20 groups I would have to calculate and type out all of them.

Comment: @geds133 I think this corrected attempt is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to divide data into `n` groups and use it in `split` to have list of dataframes.

```
n <- 4
list_df <- split(df, cut(df$value, breaks = n))
```

If you want to split the data between 0-1 into `n` groups you can do :

```
list_df <- split(df, cut(df$value, seq(0, 1, length.out = n + 1)))
```

Comment: This has not split the groups in relation to 0 to 1. My first group is -0.0002 to 0.208. It is splitting by the data itself not range 0 to 1.

Comment: If I read your question it states `I wish to split this dataframe into X amount of groups based upon the values column.`. Yes this divides the data into groups based on your `value` column. Nor 0 nor 1 is in your data. I think the updated answer will do what you need.

Comment: Apologies, I have fixed the question.

Comment: The answers unfortunately don't work on my question. The first, uses a package that I am unable to use, which has been updated in the question. The final answer splits off a column called `i` which my dataframe doesn't contain. The other answer doesn't use dataframe at all.

Comment: My answers don't use any package. Are you talking about the duplicates marked?

Comment: Yes sorry I assumed you had put them as no one else decided to comment.

Comment: @geds133 My answer with `seq` doesn't give you the expected output?